# Appending / combine arrays under for loop

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get all the possible triplet combinations using Perl,
how do I combine $x1 $x2 $x3 to get AAA AAB AAC ....... DDD ?

```
@myArray = qw/A B C D/;

i=0;
for my $x1 (@myArray) {
    for my $x2 (@myArray) {
        for my $x3 (@myArray) {


        }
    } 
}
```

my array should look like this , please avoid  ' ' ;
eg : AAB is @newarray[1] and @newarray[1][2] = B

```
triplets= ['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'AAD', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ABD', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'ACC', 'ACD', 'ADA', 'ADB', 'ADC', 'ADD', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BAC', 'BAD', 'BBA', 'BBB', 'BBC', 'BBD', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BCC', 'BCD', 'BDA', 'BDB', 'BDC', 'BDD', 'CAA', 'CAB', 'CAC', 'CAD', 'CBA', 'CBB', 'CBC', 'CBD', 'CCA', 'CCB', 'CCC', 'CCD', 'CDA', 'CDB', 'CDC', 'CDD', 'DAA', 'DAB', 'DAC', 'DAD', 'DBA', 'DBB', 'DBC', 'DBD', 'DCA', 'DCB', 'DCC', 'DCD', 'DDA', 'DDB', 'DDC', 'DDD']
```

Comment: Make sure to always use `use strict; use warnings;`!!! (We don't always include it in our answers only because we expect it to always be used.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you after?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @array;
my $letters = 'ABCD';
my @a = split '', $letters;

for my $x1 (@a) {
    for my $x2 (@a) {
        for my $x3 (@a) {
            my $str = "$x1$x2$x3";
            push @array, [$x1, $x2, $x3];
            say $str;
        }
    }
}

say Dumper(\@array);
```

Comment: how to get assigned those AAA AAB into a 2D array?
to look like @triplet = AAA AAB AAC ...... DDD

Comment: @Niransha -- can you add to your question a sample how 2D array should look like? What you have added into comment above is looks like 1 dimension array. The array will become 2 dimension only if triplet will represent an array with 3 elements. `@triplet = [ [A,A,A], [A,A,B], [A,A,C], .... , [D,D,D]]`. Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

There are four common ways to combine strings together.

1. Concatenation

   ```
   $x1 . $x2 . $x3
   ```
2. Interpolation

   ```
   "$x1$x2$x3"
   ```
3. [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)

   ```
   join("", $x1, $x2, x3)
   ```
4. [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)/[`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html)

   ```
   sprintf("%s%s%s", $x1, $x2, x3)
   ```

There are others. Use whichever one you think is most readable in the particular situation where it is needed.

For example, I find concatenation the clearest in your case.

```
my @symbols = qw( A B C D );

for my $s0 (@symbols) {
   for my $s1 (@symbols) {
      for my $s2 (@symbols) {
         say $s0.$s1.$s2;
      }
   } 
}
```

For example, `join` would be more useful when dealing with an arbitrary sequence length instead of a fixed length.

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my @symbols = qw( A B C D );
my $length = 3;

my $iter = NestedLoops([
   ( \@symbols ) x $length,
]);

while ( my @seq = $iter->() ) {
   say join "", @seq;
}
```

Comment: how to get assigned those AAA AAB into a 2D array? to look like 
@triplet = AAA AAB AAC ...... DDD

Comment: `push @triplet, $s` is used to append an element to an array. You say 2d array, but  `@triplet = ( "AAA", "AAB", "AAC" )` is just a single (1d) array.

Comment: triplet[][] = 0)  0]A 1]A 2]A     1)  AAB ... ... 63)  0D 1D 2D

Comment: That's an entirely different question. Short answer: `push @triplet, [ $s0, $s1, $s2 ];`. Is there really a reason to build this array? Is seems very wasteful to build it instead of doing the work in the loop body.

Comment: yes, I am trying to deal with RNA genetic codes, possible combinations

Comment: That doesn't address my "question" at all. You can do whatever you want to do with the sequence in the loop you already instead of putting the sequence in an array, then looping over the array later, and doing what you want to do with the sequence in that loop. The latter approach --the one you appear to be using-- is a huge waste of time and memory

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach using the glob operator.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = glob '{A,B,C,D}' x 3;

print "@data";
```

Prints:

```
AAA AAB AAC AAD ABA ABB ABC ABD ACA ACB ACC ACD ADA ADB ADC ADD BAA BAB BAC BAD BBA BBB BBC BBD BCA BCB BCC BCD BDA BDB BDC BDD CAA CAB CAC CAD CBA CBB CBC CBD CCA CCB CCC CCD CDA CDB CDC CDD DAA DAB DAC DAD DBA DBB DBC DBD DCA DCB DCC DCD DDA DDB DDC DDD
```

Comment: can these data retrieve as a 2D array @data[ ][ ] .. ?